# makefile extension

Tags: c, makefile

I'm writing a C program using gcc in cygwin. My question is, how do you create a makefile? I mean, what file-extension does it have? I know how to write simple rules, but I can't save a file in the text-editor with the right extension?
Impossible to find any info about this...
This is prolly a super-newbie question. So let the flaming begin. :-P

Comment: Use whichever file extension you like. For example, call it `makefile`, or you could call it `makefile.mytotallyawesomemakefiletypeoffile`

Comment: Well on a Linux machine it usually doesn't have an extension at all - it's just "makefile" or "Makefile".  You can call it anything you want and use the `-f` option to tell "make" which to use.

Comment: If your text editor can't save a file called `Makefile`, use a better text editor.  e.g. emacs, vim, notepad++, or basically anything that doesn't suck.

Answer (score 22):

As you are using Cygwin which in turn means that you are using GNU make, I cite the [relevant portion of the GNU make manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Makefile-Names):

> 3.2 What Name to Give Your Makefile
>
> By default, when make looks for the
>   makefile, it tries the following
>   names, in order: GNUmakefile, makefile
>   and Makefile. Normally you should call
>   your makefile either makefile or
>   Makefile. (We recommend Makefile
>   because it appears prominently near
>   the beginning of a directory listing,
>   right near other important files such
>   as README.) The first name checked,
>   GNUmakefile, is not recommended for
>   most makefiles. You should use this
>   name if you have a makefile that is
>   specific to GNU make, and will not be
>   understood by other versions of make.
>   Other make programs look for makefile
>   and Makefile, but not GNUmakefile.

[...]

> If you want to use a nonstandard name for your makefile, you can specify the makefile name with the 
>   ‘-f’ or ‘--file’ option. The arguments ‘-f name’ or ‘--file=name’ tell make to read the file name 
>   as the makefile. If you use more than one ‘-f’ or ‘--file’ option, you can specify several 
>   makefiles. All the makefiles are effectively concatenated in the order specified. The default 
>   makefile names GNUmakefile, makefile and Makefile are not checked automatically if you specify ‘-f’ 
>   or ‘--file’.

Answer (score 11):

The default filename for a makefile is `Makefile`; this is the name that GNU Make looks for when you run it without any options. The `-f` argument lets you specify an alternate filename if desired.

Comment: Actually the names GNU make looks for are specified [in the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Makefile-Names): "it tries the following names, in order: GNUmakefile, makefile and Makefile".

Comment: Fair enough. But most people that write makefiles use that name.

Answer (score 7):

In the few places where I've seen extensions used on makefile names they have generally been either `.make` or `.gmk`, and even then those extensions are usually reserved for makefile *fragments* that are included by master files given one of the default names.

Answer (score 5):

They are usually named `Makefile`, or `makefile`. No extension. That's just convention, though.

It's not trivial to write a makefile, look up a guide or tutorial =)

Answer (score 1):

A makefile is usually just called `Makefile`.

Answer (score 1):

You can name them whatever you like, but ".mak" looks right.

... google ... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380049%28VS.85%29.aspx ... yeah

Comment: Only if you invoke make with option -f to tell it which makefile to use.

Answer (score 1):

Makefiles don't usually have an extension. They're typically called 'makefile' or 'Makefile'. Sometimes, when someone writes a complex set of makefiles that include each other, the included files get a .mak extension to indicate that they're makefiles even though they aren't called 'makefile'.

Answer (score -2):

Open your favorite text editor, and create a file named `Makefile`.

Content might vary, but, provided you have a program called `hello.c` a very, very simple `Makefile` to compile it could be:

```
hello: hello.c
     gcc -Wall hello.c -o hello.exe
```

After that you run run from `cygwin` shell:

```
$ ls
hello.c Makefile
$ make
....
```

And your `Makefile` will try to compile `hello.c`. If everything goes as expected, you can run the `hello.exe` program by executing the following shell command:

```
$ ./hello.exe
```

Here's a nice tutorial on [Makefiles](http://www.cs.colby.edu/maxwell/courses/tutorials/maketutor/).