# How to run Makefile in mac

Tags: makefile, xamarin.ios, static-libraries, fat-binaries

I want to create a fat library in mac. So I foll [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/binding-objective-c/walkthrough?tabs=windows). I copied the content of makefile into an edit text and renamed it to `Makefile.mak`. I opened the terminal in where the makefile is located and types "make" in the terminal and hit enter. I am getting an error that "Makefile is not found". What would be the reason for this? Where I made a mistake?
Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [makefile extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3962552/makefile-extension)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your makefile is incorrectly named. You need to rename your Makefile.mak back to 'makefile'; that's what the make command is looking for.

Comment: is it a text file?

Comment: Yep, makefiles are ascii plain text.

Answer (score 6):

`make` looks for files with name `GNUmakefile`, `makefile` or `Makefile`. If you change your file's name to one of these, you can run it without a problem. If you still want to use that name, you must run the `make` with `-f` flag. Running command should be like this:

`$make -f <file_name>`

In your case:

`$make -f Makefile.mak`